# Karma coverage always coming empty

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, karma-runner, karma-coverage

I've been trying to run karma coverage for a couple of days now only to find an empty blank page as below. 
[image: Karma coverage empty report]

Here's my configuration:

```
var path = require('path');

var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.common');

module.exports = function (config) {
  var _config = {
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      { pattern: './karma-shim.js', watched: false }
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      './karma-shim.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap', 'coverage']
    },
    client: {
      captureConsole: false
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,

    webpackMiddleware: {
      stats: 'errors-only'
    },

    coverageReporter: {
      dir: 'coverage/',
      reporters: [{
        type: 'json',
        dir: 'coverage',
        subdir: 'json',
        file: 'coverage-final.json'
      }]
    },

    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      src: 'coverage/json/coverage-final.json',
      reports: {
        lcovonly: 'coverage/json/lcov.info',
        html: 'coverage/html',
        'text': null
      },
      timeoutNotCreated: 1000, // default value
      timeoutNoMoreFiles: 1000 // default value
    },

    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true // please don't spam the console when running in karma!
    },
    reporters: ["mocha", "coverage", "karma-remap-istanbul"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_ERROR,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'], // you can also use Chrome

    singleRun: true
  };

  config.set(_config);

};
```

And here's my karma-shim.js file

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
require('es6-shim');
require('reflect-metadata');
require('ts-helpers');
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');

var appContext = require.context('./app', true, /\.spec\.ts/);
appContext.keys().forEach(appContext);

var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');

testing.setBaseTestProviders(browser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, browser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
```

Folder Structure is as follows: 
[image: folder structure]

Any idea what am i missing here? Help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try providing your source (test file not needed) file uner "preprocessors"? I think you are missing that.

Comment: which one? can you elaborate please?

Comment: In your karma.conf.js you have a "preprocessors" tag.. I see only shim file there. You need to providing path for your source code as well. Coverage is always generated for source code. so it should have something like 'app/**/*.js'... I dont think you need shim file there.. so remove that and try with only source file..

Comment: the shim file has this configuration: require.context('./app', true, /\.spec\.ts/); you don't think it is needed?

Comment: I have never worked with webpack, so, I am suggesting based on my understanding that preprocessor is looking for your source file and we are not providing it. So, let's give it a try and use that. Hope that works.

Comment: so I have a bundle file, i did this in the preprocessors: './dist/app.bundle.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap','coverage']

Comment: did it work? if no, can you show your directory structure? where is test where is the source code that the test is trying to test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122226/discussion-between-joe-saad-and-typescripter).

Comment: i just edited the question with the detailed folder structure

Comment: Did you have any success with putting that source path? Can you give me path of a source file and its corresponding test file wrt your structure

Comment: I'm having a similar issue running Angular2. The setup is similar like yours, were you able to resolve your `coverage` issue?

Comment: @JoeSaad Hey man just wanted to check, have you got the solution of your above problem. I am also facing the same empty coverage report issue and really appreciate if you could share the solution with us as an answer to your question. I am also not using `angular-cli` for the configurations and trying to set up manually.

Comment: @MukeshRawat no, i never got a solution for that

Comment: @JoeSaad that's not a good news for me anyways. Please, could I ask you what you did for the coverage then in your application if the above one was not resolved? Maybe it could be helpful in my case as well.

Comment: I stopped working on that project, sorry wish i could help. it was more fresh in my mind when i posted the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your karma config is clearly **missing a reference to the source**.

Please modify config as follows:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    var _config = {
        [...]
        preprocessors: {
            // Remove coverage as preprocessor for your tests - 
            // Istambul (runs coverage behind the scene for karma) will 
            // instrumentate this
            './karma-shim.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
            // Add path to your source (.js or .ts - depands on your project)
            './index.ts': [ 'coverage' ]
        },
        [...]
    },
    [...]
}
```

**Explanation:** coverage tests your code against your unit tests - you need to supply entry point for your code to get Karma analyse coverage.

**Extras - adding karma-coverage plugin:**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    var _config = {
        [...]
        plugins: [
            require( 'karma-coverage' )
        ],
        [...]
    },
    [...]
}
```

**Extras - karma & typescript files:**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    var _config = {
        [...]
        plugins: [
            require( '@angular/cli/plugins/karma' )
        ],
        [...]
    },
    [...]
    preprocessors: {
        './src/test.ts': [ '@angular/cli' ],
        './index.ts': [ 'coverage' ]
    },
    [...]
    mime: {
       'text/x-typescript': [ 'ts', 'tsx' ]
    },
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Is the 'coverage' preprocessor referencing the "karma-coverage" plugin ?
If so how do you make karma-coverage handle TypeScript files ? It seems to only deal with JavaScript files.

Comment: @SaadBenbouzid you need to import karma-coverage plugin like - I have updated answer above. Karma will take it from there. When it comes to the typescript you obviously need to use some extra preprocessor eg. karma-tsc-preprocessor (I have not tested this one!) or one I use day-to-day in angular projects angular-cli. Also added to the answer above. Hope this will help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you run the test, add the `--code-coverage` flag. This solved my problem. For example:

```
ng test --watch=false --code-coverage
```

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same problem, and I've tried everything I could find on the Internet, but nothing worked. So I solved it in **the following HARD but VERY SIMPLE way**:

1. Create a new folder, or delete all the content of the existing folder of your project (**YOU'D  NEED TO ADD, COMMIT, AND PUSH EVERYTHING IF YOU DELETE THE CONTENT**), and then clone the same project all over again.
2. As usual, run command "npm install".
3. Then copy the following karma.conf.js file content to replace your own karma.conf.js file content:

   ```
    module.exports = function (config) {
      config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
          require('karma-jasmine'),
          require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
          require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
          require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
          require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client: {
          clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
          dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
          reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
          fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        restartOnFileChange: false,
      });
    };
   ```

Most likely, it's the **'coverage'** part that is wrong in

```
    dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
```

In my case, the original setup was

```
    dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './../coverage/360-app'),
```

which gave me a hard time. But since you set it up wrong in the beginning, it'd be hard to get it right even if you change it.

After I did the re-clone, I started to have everything I want:
[image]

Good luck to everyone.